# Get and display related products in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, woocommerce, product

I have included WooCommerce related products in a theme with the following:

```
<?php wc_get_template( 'single-product/related.php' ); ?>
```

This has been copied into my template and is executing.

However, even though I have added various upsells with this product the `$related_products` variable (used in the loop) is NULL. Is there any other variables at play in order to start showing these related products?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec - done mate, many thanks for your help, no doubt you'll show up on anything I tag woocommerce in the future. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need much more than that *(and the post_id need to be a product)*:

```
global $product; // If not set…

if( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ){
    $product = wc_get_product(get_the_id());
}

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'columns'        => 4,
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
    'order'          => 'desc',
);

$args['related_products'] = array_filter( array_map( 'wc_get_product', wc_get_related_products( $product->get_id(), $args['posts_per_page'], $product->get_upsell_ids() ) ), 'wc_products_array_filter_visible' );
$args['related_products'] = wc_products_array_orderby( $args['related_products'], $args['orderby'], $args['order'] );

// Set global loop values.
wc_set_loop_prop( 'name', 'related' );
wc_set_loop_prop( 'columns', $args['columns'] );

wc_get_template( 'single-product/related.php', $args );
```

Or in a shorter way *(which will give you the same)*:

```
global $product;

if( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ){
    $product = wc_get_product(get_the_id());
}

woocommerce_related_products( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'columns'        => 4,
    'orderby'        => 'rand'
) );
```

Both ways are tested and works…

Comment: In your woocommerce_related_products() function, you used 3 closing brackets instead of 2. Your current code will not work, you only need 2 closing brackets. Otherwise, the code works.

Comment: @anthonyCam Sorry but I see only 2 closing curve brackets in the woocommerce_related_products() function code there  and not 3… Your are making a confusion I think.

Comment: The last shorthand did not work for me, the one above did

Comment: Shorthand code work for me, however it causes HTML structure error. The first link is unclosed. How can I fix it?