# WooCommerce wc_get_related_products function is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

As a developer, i tried to develop a WooCommerce based plugin. I want to add related product in `woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button` hook in single product page:

```php
function custom_popup_on_add_to_cart(){
    global $product;

    $related_products=wc_get_related_products($product->get_id());

    var_dump($related_products); // Is empty
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button','custom_popup_on_add_to_cart');
```

Comment: I added your code but it's still not working. Can you check it from here https://github.com/Ferdaussk/woo-product-recommendations/blob/master/woo-product-recommendations.php#L70

Answer (score 2):

Note that **products can be Related** to each other in three ways: Up-Sells, Cross-Sells **or by having the same tags or categories**, which is required for "related products".

See: [Set up Related Products, Up-Sells and Cross-Sells](https://woocommerce.com/document/related-products-up-sells-and-cross-sells/)

So if the function `wc_get_related_products()` doesn't output an array of related products IDs, it's because you need to set your categories and tags for each product.

---

There are 2 ways to add related product after Add to Cart button in single product pages.

Simpler way:

```php
// Remove related products from their default location
remove_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20);
// Add back related products in a different location
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 10);
```

or the other way (allowing to change arguments):

```php
// Remove related products from their default location
remove_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20);

// Add back related products in a different location
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'custom_output_related_products');
function custom_output_related_products() {
    woocommerce_related_products( array(
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'columns'        => 4,
        'orderby'        => 'rand', // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine.
    ));
}
```

Both ways work.

---

if you want to remove the title "Related product" use:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_related_products_heading', '__return_false' );
```

if you want to change the title "Related product" use:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_related_products_heading', 'custom_related_products_heading' );
function custom_related_products_heading( $heading ) {
    return __( 'Similar products', 'woocommerce' );
}
```

Related: [Get and display related products in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53356016/get-and-display-related-products-in-woocommerce/53356356#53356356)

Comment: I added your code but it's still not working. Can you check it from here https://github.com/Ferdaussk/woo-product-recommendations/blob/master/woo-product-recommendations.php#L70

Comment: Sorry, but my answer code works… So there is something wrong on your side.